# Tabulator - render column formatted with HTML

Tags: tabulator

I have a Tabulator table which has one column for my icons. To draw my icons, I have the column data stored as HTML text, and choose the column 'formatter' to be 'html'.
Currently my table has a few hundred rows.

When I load the table, the icons appear as expected for the visible rows. However, when I scroll beyond the initial visible 'window' (and past the 'buffer' of the Virtual DOM), the icons are not rendered.

How do I force a row to render its HTML formatted field, when I scroll to it within the visible window?

Comment: You can try [disabling the virtual DOM](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/layout#virtual-dom-disable) if you haven't done so already.  The performance hit for a few hundred rows may be negligible but of course this depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Timur. I just tested that, but the performance was so slow that it caused the page to crash.

Comment: Is your data paginated?  Do you know how many rows you need to display at once?  Another option maybe to use the `renderVerticalBuffer` option to set the buffer to something closer to your table height which can be calculated based on how many rows you display at once.  Also, how are you loading the icons?  Is it from a framework such as bootstrap?  Can you include a Minimal, Reproducible Example by any chance?

Comment: @Timur, thanks! Your question asking how my icons are being loaded prompted me to review my code. The html field includes a canvas element on each row. The icons are being drawn into canvas elements by easeljs, once the table is built. 
I now realise that it would only draw the icons into the rows that are within the buffer range. 
As a solution, I now force the icons to be redrawn on the table vertical scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Tabulator was rendering the HTML just fine, it was my code that wasn't drawing icons into the HTML elements as they were being created.